# I'm trying to put this value into a row into the table. How do I fix this?

Tags: python

Input:

```
street_number = random.randint(1,300)
street_name = ['Main', 'Apache', 'Elm', 'Cedar', 'Oak', 'Sunset', 'Willow', 'Spruce','Columbine', 'Laurel',
               'Ridge', 'Hillside', 'Park', 'Church', 'Texana','Magnolia','Lakeview', 'Hickory','Washington', 'Wilson',
               'Winchester', 'Cypress', 'Evergreen', 'Hemlock','Pleasant']
streetname2 = ['Road', 'Way', 'Street', 'Avenue','Boulevard', 'Lane', 'Drive', 'Place', 'Terrace']

street_address = "{} {} {}".format(street_number, random.choice(street_name), random.choice(streetname2))


from prettytable import PrettyTable

x = PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["Street Adress"]

x.add_row([print(street_address)])

print(x)
```

output:

```
124 Hillside Terrace

+---------------+

| Street Adress |


+---------------+

|      None     |

+---------------+
```

(Ignore the format of the table, idk why it's spaced out like that)

Comment: describe problem in question's body, not in title. And show what result you expect.

Comment: I don't understand why you use `print()` in `x.add_row([print(street_address)])` - `print()` is used only to display on screen (not to format text and assign to variable) and it always returns `None` - so you have `x.add_row([None])`. You should use directly `x.add_row([street_address])`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `print()` in

```
x.add_row([print(street_address)])
```

`print()` is used only to send text on screen - not to assign text to variable. And not to format text. Command `format()` will format text without `print()`.

`print()` sends text on screen and it always returns `None` so you have

```
x.add_row([None])
```

You have to use directly

```
x.add_row([street_address])
```

---

```
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import random


street_number = random.randint(1,300)
street_name = ['Main', 'Apache', 'Elm', 'Cedar', 'Oak', 'Sunset', 'Willow', 'Spruce','Columbine', 'Laurel',
               'Ridge', 'Hillside', 'Park', 'Church', 'Texana','Magnolia','Lakeview', 'Hickory','Washington', 'Wilson',
               'Winchester', 'Cypress', 'Evergreen', 'Hemlock','Pleasant']
streetname2 = ['Road', 'Way', 'Street', 'Avenue','Boulevard', 'Lane', 'Drive', 'Place', 'Terrace']

street_address = "{} {} {}".format(street_number, random.choice(street_name), random.choice(streetname2))


x = PrettyTable()

x.field_names = ["Street Adress"]

x.add_row([street_address])

print(x)
```

Result:

```
+--------------------+
|   Street Adress    |
+--------------------+
| 164 Hemlock Avenue |
+--------------------+
```